# How to set a class Name as a method's parameter?

Tags: java, class, generics, reflection, annotations

I would like to send a class name as a parameter of method. I would like to use(execute) it like that.

```
orderDao.getTheMostFrequentType(EmployeeOrder.class);
```

I have this code

```
@Override
public String getTheMostFrequentType(Class<T> orderClass){
    String tableName = orderClass.getAnnotation(Table.class).name();
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT STATS_MODE(signed_by_id) FROM " + tableName;
    String result = (String)getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sqlQuery).uniqueResult();
    return result;
}
```

But it executing attempts gives me:

```
getTheMostFrequentType("org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T") method cannot be applied in "java.lang.entities.EmployeeOrder"
```

May be there is another classes should i import instead of apache.poi. But which one? What i do wrong?

Comment: what is this  `T`? Why does it comes from apache.poi?

Comment: What is `orderClass`

Comment: <T> means generic type.

Comment: Check your import statements.

Comment: Your `Class<T>` doesn't mean generic here because it seems you've imported a class named `T` from an Apache library --> `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T`. I think it happened cause your class doesn't define `T` (we can see that your method neither). Trying to resolve this problem, you did what your IDE suggested you, importing a known `T` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the problem was caused by not declaring a type parameter `T` but importing an actual type `T`.

The problem was solved by replacing `Class<T>` with `Class<?>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using T **in a method of class level**, you must define it first in class / method definition, unless "T" is unknown.

```
public class MainClass<T> extends Parent
{...}
```

or

```
public <T> String getTheMostFrequentType(Class<T> orderClass)
{...}
```

Another option is not define specific type of T with mark "?"
in your case i think it's better solution

> **TIP**: Better to not make code complex with generic if it's not really
>   needed.

like that:

```
public String getTheMostFrequentType(Class<?> orderClass)
{...}
```

Comment: Why `you MUST define it first in class definition` ? A non-static generic method is allowed in Java

Comment: @Holger - it's just an example, i agree in this case generic is not really needed, he can just use "?"